# I'm getting the formula instead of the cell content

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have this code:

```
String fname = "C:/Users/slim/Desktop/xlsxFiles/plan.xlsx"; 
            InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(fname);
            Workbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inp);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            for (Row row : sheet) {
                System.out.println(row.getCell(0));
                System.out.println(row.getCell(11));
            }
```

The problem I'm facing seems kinda weird to me, because it is my first time dealing with POI.

The content of `cell 0` is a date and I have no problems with it at all, but the content of `cell 11` wich is supposed to be a number is returning the formula used to get the content. Here is a sample output:

```
31-Aug-2013
L3/5
30-Sep-2013
L3*2/5
31-Oct-2013
L3*3/5
30-Nov-2013
L3*4/5
31-Dec-2013
L3
31-Jan-2014
P8
28-Feb-2014
P9
31-Mar-2014
P10
```

and so on...

What I need to do is to show the actual content of the cell, not the formula. I'm sure that I'm missing something small, but as a complete beginner, I'm not able to spot it.

Comment: You'll need to [read this](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html)

Comment: Finf the following answer, must help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510112/how-to-read-cell-value-from-formula-cell-using-apache-poi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual content of the cell is the formula; Excel just usually doesn't show it (instead, it shows the result of evaluating the formula).

[This document](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) explains how to calculate the formula but often, this isn't necessary because Excel saves the last calculated value along with the formula.

So `getCell(11).getNumericCellValue()` might be enough.

Note that this method throws exceptions when being used on cells with text.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell` Is there a way to convert it somehow?

Comment: If you get this error, then you called `.getNumericCellValue()` on a cell without a formula and without numeric value. I suggest that you ask each cell for its type (`getCellType()`) and then call the correct method to read the value.

Comment: Hey it worked! Now I have another issue with the null values, but I will find how it works. HUGE thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            System.out.println(row.getCell(0).getRichStringCellValue().getString());
            System.out.println(row.getCell(11).getRichStringCellValue().getString());
        }
```

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric formula cell` Is there a way to convert it?